# Unable to get result from ZXing barcode scanner

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, onactivityresult

I am trying to implement barcode scanner activity in my Android application but I heard that it's not possible to do so without asking the user to install the ZXing bar code scanner.

So what I did is that I used the ZXing integrator class for initiating a scan here is my code. But I am unable to show the result in the two text views. I must mention that the scan is started and the result is shown in the barcode scanner window itself, but then nothing comes on the ScanCodeActivity layout which has two text views on it.

I also would like to know if it's possible to return the result from th eweb into my text views.

I used this link as reference:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ScanCodeActivity extends Activity {

    private Button scan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scancodelayout);

        scan= (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);

        Button scanBtn  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        final TextView  formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        final TextView contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);

        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(ScanCodeActivity.this);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
           if (requestCode == 0) {
               IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
               if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                   if (scanningResult != null) {
                       final TextView  formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
                       final TextView contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
                       String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                       String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Content:" + scanContent + " Format:" + scanFormat , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                       formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                       contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
                     //we have a result
                     }
                   else{
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
               } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                  // Handle cancel
                  Log.i("App","Scan unsuccessful");
               }
         }
      }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `onActivityResult` called? Are you sure that the `requestCode` is 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `if (requestCode == 0)` check from your `onActivityResult()` method similar to the example from the library's [wiki page](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent).

Note: You are checking for the wrong `requestCode`. The library uses `0x0000c0de` (see [the source](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java)) instead of `0`.

Comment: This was very useful now i have one more question

Comment: How can i compare the value returned by the scaner to a string array? i want to know if the value returned by the scanner in "Content" matches any of the values in my string array initialized in the same ScanCodeActivity

Comment: You could iterate through all elements in this array and compare the returned value to each element until you either find a match or checked all elements without finding a match.

Comment: thanks a lot ur answer for partly useful the scanner app only reads code and says plain text but doesnt show anything in the text view.. generally the scanner apps display results from web this one doesnt show anything ... how can i make it display result from web and resturn that result in my text view...

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want but maybe you'd like to post a new question.

Comment: the zing app available from playstore when it scans a barcode it shows option for websearch.. but my app starts the zing scaner app and also reads the barcode .. if i cancel the scan "cancelled" msg is set into the text view.. but if i continue with the scan the code is identified bu nothng is shown in the text view. it just flashed the code and returns to my activity. i want to be able to launch a web search with the identified barcode?

Comment: Does `scanningResult.getContents()` return `null` or an empty String or what?

Comment: i dont what it returns because i export the apk and test it on my device.. i cant test on emualtor because it doest have camera to scan barcode.. also i cant test on a live device connected to eclipse because i havent configured it.. but if i cancel scan.. the mesage "cancelled" is displayed in the text view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358203/android-barcode-scanner-with-outpan-database